# Using several builds error occurs INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android, facebook, manifest

I have the following structure gradle:

```
productFlavors {
        main {
            applicationId = "com.mayapp.main"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 5
            versionName '2.0'
        }
        free {
            applicationId = "com.mayapp.free"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 5
            versionName '2.0'
        }
        full {
            applicationId = "com.mayapp.full"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 5
            versionName '2.0'
        }
}
```

In the main build own the only manifest file, it this provider of Facebook.

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true" />
```

But when trying to install another build for example the free presents a INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error. How can I resolve this conflict since all builds use the same id of Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this conflict.
For example, in the build free I created a AndroidManifest.xml with the following format:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mayapp.free"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

...
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider0123456789"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            tools:replace="android:authorities"
            android:exported="true"/>
```

With this solved my conflict.
Detail, had to create more applications in the portal Facebook, one for each build.

Answer (score 0):

If you want install different apps in the same device, please make sure there is no same provider (authorities) in them, or u should uninstall the first one

Comment: Yes, they will be installed on the same machine but, as I do on the issue of provider of Facebook? I have to create a Facebook application portal for each type of build flavor?